# Cannot get translated string using __($string, $textDomain) function in plugin(Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am stuck at the next thing. I am trying to add a translation to my plugin but somehow the translated string is not coming back.

First of all, I started adding the text-domain the file on my plugin:

```
/**
 * Plugin Name: MyPlugin
 * Plugin URI:
 * Description: 
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: Daan 
 * Author URI: 
 * Text Domain: domain
 **/
```

Second I added an `__('auto', 'domain');`  function to one of my PHP files. And I can find it back in local translate under the textdomain in my plugin. So I have translated one (auto means car).

[image]

After this, I checked the lang of the website (to make sure it is Dutch, formal).
Then I try to dump `__('auto', 'domain');` but I get the same string back as I put in. But it should be translated.

After that, I was checking if the `__('` function was not loaded yet. So I threw it into an init hook. But this also had no result (get the same string in as out).

```
public function init(){
        add_action( 'init', [$this, 'initDaan'] );

    }

    public function initDaan(){

        var_dump( __('auto', 'domain'));

    }
```

Is there a special way or function you need to call to get the translations on a plugin?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_e/  This function perhaps ? Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out. It was not ready on the go. So I added an plugin_loaded hook. And add load_plugin_textdomain

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action('plugins_loaded', [$this, 'register']);
    }

    public function register()
    {
        load_plugin_textdomain('domain');
        new Cli\GetTable();
        new ShortCode\RegisterShortCode();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Loco translate, click on "plugins", then select the plugin you want to translate.
Before you translate it, you need to click on "Edit template file (.POT)", then click on "Sync" (it will look for the last changes in the plugin) and save it.

Then you go to the language you want to translate, find the word you want to translate, translate it and save it.

Comment: First of all, Bobo thanks for your answer. 
The problem is not that I cannot get the translated words. They are synced in the .POT file using the sync button in Loco translate. That part is working (I can translate the world in Local translate). When I am using the `__('auto', 'domain')` the domain don't seems to be existing. Even if I can find it back in Local translate. When I use the `_e` function. I get the same result. The text-domain don't seems to exist and I don't know why